# Clip polygon to whole features that intersect with other polygon - QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, clip

I have a Polygon (MultiPolygon) with lots of features. I have another thin polygon that overlays onto it.  I can use the latter to clip the former. But I don't want to clip the former exactly to the latter, I want to clip the former to the whole features that intersect with the latter. I.e. clip the polygon down but don't clip the features that are covered by the mask layer - clip it so it's just what's in yellow here:

[image]

It seems simple but I have tried the clip and intersect tools without success.

Comment: Select by location -> Export selected features.

Comment: The tool *Extract by location* will combine @BenW's suggestion into one step.